# Vue.js - can't access the properties of a prop object

Tags: vue.js

I am creating then passing an object using pdfjs in to a child Vue component. When I do so, I can access the object itself, but I cannot access any properties of the object.

This is the case during all of the lifecycle hooks.

```
<i-slide-deck-pdf // calling child vue component
    v-if="true"
    :slideDeckItem="fetchPDF('/static/intropdf.pdf')"
    :current-user-progress="currentUserProgress"
    @i-progress="putProgressTracker"
    @i-slide-change="onSlideChange"
/>

...

fetchPDF(url) { // function being used to create the object
  let pdfItem = new Object();
  import(
    'pdfjs-dist/webpack'
  ).
    then(pdfjs => pdfjs.getDocument(url)).
    then(pdf => {
      pdfItem.pdf = pdf;
      pdfItem.pages = range(1, pdf.numPages).map(number => pdf.getPage(number));
      pdfItem.pageCount = pdfItem.pages.length;
    })
  return pdfItem;
},

...

props: { // prop call in child component
  slideDeckItem: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  },
}
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxkvG.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the async call hasn't completed, so you are just returning an empty object, to fix this you want to set a value inside the `then` portion of your code, and bind this to your prop, so:

```
fetchPDF(url) { // function being used to create the object
  let pdfItem = new Object();
  import(
    'pdfjs-dist/webpack'
  ).
    then(pdfjs => pdfjs.getDocument(url)).
    then(pdf => {
      pdfItem.pdf = pdf;
      pdfItem.pages = range(1, pdf.numPages).map(number => pdf.getPage(number));
      pdfItem.pageCount = pdfItem.pages.length;

      // This should be inside the "then"
      this.slideDeckItem = pdfItem; 
    })
},
```

You'll then want to declare `slideDeckItem` in your parent data property, and bind that to your component's prop:

```
<i-slide-deck-pdf
    v-if="true"
    :slideDeckItem="slideDeckItem"
    :current-user-progress="currentUserProgress"
    @i-progress="putProgressTracker"
    @i-slide-change="onSlideChange"
/>
```

I've made a JSFiddle, to give you the basic idea, although I've used a timeout to simulate the async call:  http://jsfiddle.net/ga1o4k5c/

You may also want to take a look at [how Promises work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)